# Informatica: Converting a table into multiple target tables based on one column.

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

In my source table data is

```
s_name,p_name,value
s1 ,   p1,     10
s1 ,   p2,     xyz
s1 ,   p3,     abc
s2 ,   p1,     20
s2 ,   p2,     xyz
s2 ,   p3,     abc
```

I want two target tables, first table is based on sname s1, second table based on sname s2. Both table contains contains p_name and value.

The target table data like as

Table s1

```
p_name,value 
p1,    10
p2,    xyz
p3,    abc
```

Table s2

```
p_name,value 
p1,    20
p2,    xyz
p3,    abc
```

Comment: Thanks Marek, I have not tried let me try but seems it should work in my case. Thanks for giving attention to my problem.

Comment: Using Normalization Transformation also you should be able to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Router** transformation routes the rows of data into a separate output group based on conditions defined for each group.

For your example you will need two define two output groups with the following conditions:

- group `s1_rows` - condition `s_name = 's1'`
- group `s2_rows` - condition `s_name = 's2'`